# Dynamic casting to a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, casting

I'm trying to get to the `Cases.Values` property of [System.Activities.Statements.Switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd647669%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) object. The problem is that I cannot cast `Activity` object at runtime to `Switch<>` type (which derives from it).

```
var switchType = activity.GetType();
bool isSwitch = (switchType.IsGenericType && switchType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Switch<>));

if (isSwitch)
{
    Type[] genericArgumentTypes = switchType.GetGenericArguments();
    if (genericArgumentTypes.Length > 0)
    {
        var switchStatement = (Switch<genericArgumentTypes[0]>) activity;  //that's incorrect
        foreach (var aCase in switchStatement.Cases.Values)
        {
            ProcessActivity(aCase, dataSets, context);
        }
    }
}
```

Also,

```
dynamic switchStatement = activity;
foreach (var aCase in switchStatement.Cases.Values)
{
    ProcessActivity(aCase, dataSets, context);
}
```

throws an error, that the property is not there, while debugger is showing it's not true. The `T` is irrelevant for me - I need only the `Cases` collection.

**EDIT**

Actually, I've found even cleaner solution, than the one I set as an answer.

```
dynamic switchStatement = activity;
var cases = switchStatement.Cases as IEnumerable;
if (cases != null)
{
    foreach (dynamic aCase in cases)
    {
        ProcessActivity(aCase.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: How variable `activity` is defined?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.activities.activity(v=vs.100).aspx

`Switch<>` is inheriting from `Activity` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var switchType = activity.GetType();
var prop = switchType.GetProperty("Cases", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public 
            | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance); //move it outside of the method and use the same property for every time you call the method since it's performance expansive.
bool isSwitch = (switchType.IsGenericType && switchType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Switch<>));

if (isSwitch)
{
        IEnumerable dictionary = prop.GetValue(activity,null) as IDictionary;
        foreach (var item in dictionary.Values)
        {
            ProcessActivity(item, dataSets, context);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm getting 
`Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.` exception on dictionary object assignment.

Comment: Edited, now it will work. you just need to do the `GetValue()` method on a property you have got using `GetType()` dynamically

Comment: Unfortunately, GetValue returns null if casted to `IDictionary`. If I won't cast it and use it as dynamic and I'll get the dictionary object, but again - I won't be able to get `Values` property.

Comment: Editer retry with ienumerable

Comment: Then there's no `Values` property in `dictionary` and if iterating `dictionary` collection directly, it's treated as `object` type.

Comment: This object is keyvaluepair<T,S> you can do the same with GetProperty and GetValue on it to get the value

Comment: I allowed myself to modify your code to the form that worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47034/discussion-between-tarec-and-some1pr0)

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

But instead of your loop, put:

```
var process = typeof(CurrentHelperClass).GetMethod("ProcessSwitch`1").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(genericArgumentTypes[0]));
 process.Invoke(null,new object[]{activity});
```

and define a new method in the same class:

```
static void ProcessSwitch<T>(Switch<T> switchStatement)
{
    foreach (var aCase in switchStatement.Cases.Values)
    {
        ProcessActivity(aCase, dataSets, context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Switch<> is a part of System.Activities namespace. How can I force library class to implement an interface?

Comment: Oh right, I didnt realize that. Are you instanciating the class yourself ? If yes, you could define a class MySwitch<T> : Switch<T>, ISwitch. If no, I'll propose a new answer (a bit more complicated)

Comment: No. `Switch<>` is a node in a workflow. I'm reviewing each node (Activity) of it and I cannot modify the activities types used.

Comment: Any way to do that in a static method? :) Because I'm using it in a helper class basically..

Comment: @Olivier: I'd remove the sample with `ISwitch`.

Comment: GetMethod("ProcessSwitch") returns null. Is it possible, that it is not included into build because it is formally never used?

Comment: nope. that is because I made a mistake :) it should be "ProcessSwitch`1"

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience, but it still can't find the method.

Comment: input typeof(YourType).GetMethods() in a spy window, and find your method

Comment: @Tarec Actually it shouldn't be "ProcessSwitch`1", the problem is `GetMethod` only finds public methods by default. Use `GetMethod("ProcessSwitch", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)`. I think this is the cleanest solution because the dynamic lookup is confined to your own class only.